# Pagination with React doesn't work, all items are still displayed on screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I have a pagination made with a `react-paginate` package called react-paginate here is the link to the doc. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paginate

I have implemented it in my App which is a notes diary, the user creates notes and these are dynamically saved in the localStorage and displayed on screen, well, I have established that there are 6 notes per page, that is, when there is a seventh note, it should not be displayed unless the user goes to page 2, when there are 13 notes page 3 and so ...

The functionality of my component that I have called `Pagination` works correctly, it is dynamic, I have right now testing 13 notes, so it shows me 3 pages, if I had 12, it would show me 2.

The problem is that although my pagination is correct, the 13 notes are being shown on the screen, when it should be 6 - 6 - 1.

I leave you the code to see if we can find the error, greetings and thanks in advance.

The prop that `Pagination` receives called `data`, are basically the notes that are created dynamically in `App.js`. `const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);`

Component `Pagination`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';
import '../styles/Pagination.css';

const Pagination = (props) => {
  const { data } = props;
    
  // We start with an empty list of items.
  const [currentItems, setCurrentItems] = useState([]); 
  const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(0);
  // Here we use item offsets; we could also use page offsets
  // following the API or data you're working with.
  const [itemOffset, setItemOffset] = useState(0);
    const itemsPerPage = 6;

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch items from another resources.
    const endOffset = itemOffset + itemsPerPage;
    console.log(`Loading items from ${itemOffset} to ${endOffset}`);
    setCurrentItems(data.slice(itemOffset, endOffset));
    setPageCount(Math.ceil(data.length / itemsPerPage));
  }, [itemOffset, itemsPerPage, data]);

  // Invoke when user click to request another page.
  const handlePageClick = (event) => {
  const newOffset = (event.selected * itemsPerPage) % data.length;
  console.log(
    `User requested page number ${event.selected}, which is offset ${newOffset}`
  );
  setItemOffset(newOffset);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ReactPaginate
        breakLabel="..."
        nextLabel="next >"
        onPageChange={handlePageClick}
        pageRangeDisplayed={3}
        pageCount={pageCount}
        previousLabel="< previous"
        renderOnZeroPageCount={null}
        containerClassName="pagination"
        pageLinkClassName="page-num"
        previousLinkClassName="page-num"
        nextLinkClassName="page-num"
        activeLinkClassName="activee boxx"
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default Pagination;
```

Component `App`

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import NoteList from "./components/NoteList";
import './App.css';
import Search from "./components/Search";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Pagination from "./components/Pagination";

const App = () => {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
   const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);
   //Se encarga de mostrar la nota para escribir 
   const [showNote, setShowNote] = useState(true); //eslint-disable-line
  useEffect(() => {
    const saveNotes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes-data'));
    if (saveNotes){
      setNotes(saveNotes);
    }
    
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('notes-data', JSON.stringify(notes))
  },[notes])

  const addNote = (inputText, text) => { 
    const date = new Date();
    const newNote = {
      id: nanoid(),
      title: inputText,
      text: text,
      date: date.toLocaleString()
      
    }
    const newNotes = [newNote, ...notes];
    setNotes(newNotes)
  }
  const deleteNote = (id) => {
    var response = window.confirm("Are you sure that you want to remove the note?");
    if (response){
      const notesUpdated = notes.filter((note) => note.id !== id)
      setNotes(notesUpdated);
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className={darkMode ? 'dark-mode' : ''}>

    <div className="container">
      <Header 
        handleToggleTheme={setDarkMode}
      />
      <Search 
        handleSearchNote={setSearchText}
        setShowNote={setShowNote}
        />
      <NoteList 
        notes={notes.filter((noteText) => 
          noteText.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
        )}
        handleAddNote={addNote}
        handleDeleteNote={deleteNote}
      />
      <Pagination data={notes}/>
    </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you please provide us the problem example in codesandbox!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community the question it is already solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are not using `currentItems` and the paginated data is stored in that state.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-keldysh-2u72vd

**Pagination.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';
import NoteList from "./components/NoteList";
import '../styles/Pagination.css';

const Pagination = (props) => {
  const { data, searchText, handleAddNote, handleDeleteNote } = props;
    
  // We start with an empty list of items.
  const [currentItems, setCurrentItems] = useState([]); 
  const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(0);
  // Here we use item offsets; we could also use page offsets
  // following the API or data you're working with.
  const [itemOffset, setItemOffset] = useState(0);
    const itemsPerPage = 6;

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch items from another resources.
    const endOffset = itemOffset + itemsPerPage;
    console.log(`Loading items from ${itemOffset} to ${endOffset}`);
    setCurrentItems(data.slice(itemOffset, endOffset));
    setPageCount(Math.ceil(data.length / itemsPerPage));
  }, [itemOffset, itemsPerPage, data]);

  // Invoke when user click to request another page.
  const handlePageClick = (event) => {
  const newOffset = (event.selected * itemsPerPage) % data.length;
  console.log(
    `User requested page number ${event.selected}, which is offset ${newOffset}`
  );
  setItemOffset(newOffset);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <NoteList 
        notes={currentItems.filter((noteText) => 
          noteText.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
        )}
        handleAddNote={handleAddNote}
        handleDeleteNote={handleDeleteNote}
      />
      <ReactPaginate
        breakLabel="..."
        nextLabel="next >"
        onPageChange={handlePageClick}
        pageRangeDisplayed={3}
        pageCount={pageCount}
        previousLabel="< previous"
        renderOnZeroPageCount={null}
        containerClassName="pagination"
        pageLinkClassName="page-num"
        previousLinkClassName="page-num"
        nextLinkClassName="page-num"
        activeLinkClassName="activee boxx"
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default Pagination;
```

**App.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import './App.css';
import Search from "./components/Search";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Pagination from "./components/Pagination";

const App = () => {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
   const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);
   //Se encarga de mostrar la nota para escribir 
   const [showNote, setShowNote] = useState(true); //eslint-disable-line
  useEffect(() => {
    const saveNotes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes-data'));
    if (saveNotes){
      setNotes(saveNotes);
    }
    
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('notes-data', JSON.stringify(notes))
  },[notes])

  const addNote = (inputText, text) => { 
    const date = new Date();
    const newNote = {
      id: nanoid(),
      title: inputText,
      text: text,
      date: date.toLocaleString()
      
    }
    const newNotes = [newNote, ...notes];
    setNotes(newNotes)
  }
  const deleteNote = (id) => {
    var response = window.confirm("Are you sure that you want to remove the note?");
    if (response){
      const notesUpdated = notes.filter((note) => note.id !== id)
      setNotes(notesUpdated);
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className={darkMode ? 'dark-mode' : ''}>

    <div className="container">
      <Header 
        handleToggleTheme={setDarkMode}
      />
      <Search 
        handleSearchNote={setSearchText}
        setShowNote={setShowNote}
        />
      <Pagination data={notes} handleAddNote={addNote}
        handleDeleteNote={deleteNote} searchText={searchText} />
    </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I was making a codesandbox with the problem and I just see that you have already solved it, it is tremendous, YES! it is correct what you say, I have tested it and my App works completely as I want. You don't know how much I appreciate it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome, I'm glad that, you liked my answer :)

Comment: hello, I have found a small bug, and it is that the search engine stops working if the note I am looking for is on another page, for example if note x is on page 2 and I am on page 1, it doesn't show it. This is because I'm passing currentItems to the filter and not the data variable, which contains all the notes, I don't really know how to make it work. v.v

Comment: I suggest you to search all the notes with searchText in your App.js and pass the results into the Pagination component and it will solve your problem.

Comment: jumm I'm new with React, how could I do that? I made a new function in App.js with the same code to filter the notes by search engine, and I'm trying to pass it through props in the <Pagination /> component but it doesn't work. My project is becoming complicated ^^

Comment: You can create a new question and specify the problem in that and many users can see that and solve it for you

Comment: You are right thanks ^^